# match reoccurring words in string using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to match reoccurring words in a string

I've tried `re.findall( r"(\b(\w+)\b)((?=.*)\1)+ , stringToCheck )` but to no avail.

For a string like `"ball ball glass table ball glass chair"`, I would like to extract `ball, ball, glass, ball, glass` using regex. can any one help please?

Comment: ...why would you use regex for something that can so easily be achieved with `str.split` and `collections.Counter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this using regex and list comprehension as follows:

```
In [43]: s = "ball ball glass table ball glass chair"

In [68]: splitted = re.findall(r"\w+", s)

In [69]: [item for item in splitted if splitted.count(item) > 1]
Out[69]: ['ball', 'ball', 'glass', 'ball', 'glass']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not fixated on using regex, it can be done easily using the following code (as suggested by the comment on your question):

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter()

example_string = "ball ball glass table ball glass chair"
word_list = example_string.split(" ")

for word in word_list:
  cnt[word] += 1

print(cnt)
```

This can then be filtered to give only the one's where the count is greater than 1.

```
filtered = {k:v for (k,v) in cnt.items() if v > 1}
```